# Capacitance value - AC RC Circuit - Impedance Method

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis, capacitance

Here is the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCWHOX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$ 
V_i = \frac{8}{\sqrt 2} \angle0° V\\
V_c = \frac{6}{\sqrt 2} \angle45° V\\
R = 1000\space\Omega
\$

I'd like to know how to find the capacitance with these given values. What I've tried:

\$
V_c = V_i \times \frac{X_c}{R\space\space+\space\space X_c} \\
X_c = \frac{V_c\space R}{V_i\space\space - \space\space V_c}
\$

Here is the problem, just solving for Xc, I got a complex number with a angle different than -90°. So I forced Xc to be -90°, then when I solve for the capacitance **c**, I get a complex number:

\$
X_c = 1058.7141\angle 93.4716182° \\
\frac{1}{j\frac{500}{2\pi}c} = 1058.7141\angle 93.4716182° \\
c = -0.00001184768784 + j\space 7.18682779 \times 10^{-7}
\$

What am I possibly missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a malformed question because with these components, the phase angle of \$V_C\$ must be \$-90^\circ\$.  The only way it could be \$45^\circ\$ would be if there were also an inductance in the circuit.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! thanks! But the calculation is right?

Comment: @JoãoPauloOliveiraFernandes: The equations are correct up to point at which you get a value for the complex impedence, but it's not really \$X_C\$ but rather \$X_N\$ where \$N\$ is some strange compound part with the impedance you calculated.  A complex capacitance has no real physical sense.

Comment: Ok. Since the given values are right, I should have found a Xc with -90°, right? After that would be just match the complex amplitudes to find c, right?